# The document "Main.storyboard" could not be be opened

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, git, storyboard

I'm using Git and we are 2 people coding together. I pulled my friend's code, run it and it worked as it should be. Then I merged our parts and cleaned conflicts (almost all of them were in storyboard). Since i'm doing this merge process for a while, i'm not all stranger for these details. 
However, when i run the merged version of code, i get the error:

> The document "Main.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)

I can't open storyboard as interface builder either. When i try it, I get the same error. I read [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725116/the-document-mainstoryboard-storyboard-could-not-be-opened) about this error but as I mentioned, I can open and run both versions of code in my XCode before merge. Thus, there is not a font or attributed string problem.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

I got this issue, after I solve the `conflicts` which is merged by `svn`.

I could only see the source code of my `storyboard`, I could not open my `storyboard` as `interface builder`. So, after my struggle,

1)I delete the topside space line in my `storyboard` source code

2)and close my `Xcode` and `simulator`

3)restart my project

it becomes regular, oops, the space line on the source code will affect our `storyboard` ！

Comment: hats off, saved my life

Comment: For storyboard file, you right click it -> view source.

Answer (score 2):

there are conflicts in Storyboard. You can take last working code of storyboard from github. select storyboard select version editor and copy last working storyboard and replace xml with existing xml.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your storyboard still have confliction.View your storyborad as source code, then fix all conflictions. After all, open it again as Interface builder

[image: Example]

Comment: Yes, i did this. There were 6 conflicts in storyboard ( i choose my side or other side in each of conflicts) and single conflict in pbxproj file. I took it to beginning several times and do again with small differences but error occurs constantly.

Comment: I did it either. Even i restarted computer.

Comment: hum, maybe you did something wrong with your fix. I have no idea to fix. I recommend you should rollback then discard your changed, pull your friend's code (in this storyborad) then add what you did in it again.

Answer (score 1):

For me the only thing that worked was to create a new storyboard file, open the old and the new storyboards as source code, and copy the xml from the old to the new storyboard. I didn't take the whole xml, just the scope of the `<scenes> </scenes>`

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a new Storyboard file. Then cut and paste the "scenes" tags from the old and put into the new.  I then had to delete the old Storyboard from the project in order for the project to build successfully!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that storyboards don't merge very well, I think it is better to init your UI from code so there will be no troubles during merges. Anyway you should try to rollback and merge it again.

Comment: I did this rollback and re-merging at least 5-6 times :)

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned, there are likely merge conflicts in the storyboard file.

If you can't easily solve the conflict by either picking `--ours` or `--theirs`, you will have to perform the merge manually in the storyboard file.

What I do is open in in a text editor (e.g., TextEdit.app - but make sure it opens documents as plain text, in Preferences).

Then, locate any occurrence of the git conflict markers (or a portion thereof, e.g., "<<<<<"), and pick the code fragment that you want to leave (and remove the other, of course).

---

**EDIT:** As [Cong Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34218533/433373) mentioned (and I forgot), you can open storyboards as source code from within Xcode itself (see his answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Fast way to fix**

1. Copy the storyboard Id shown on the error prompt window
2. Right click on your storyboard
3. Choose Open as => Source Code
4. Search the id and delete one of the duplicateID and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest , right click on any of the files and click on finder then you will have what you need and drag and drop

Comment: have you tried that way -- Chris ? or you didn't understand what i mean.